# How to open google map links on apple map in wkwebview Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, wkwebview, apple-maps

I have an application and i am working with WKWebView. In WkWebView i have "get directions" links. When i press the "get directions" link, it must open a map. But nothing opens. I can get links so my links are like this, "maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=1234567,1234567&ll=". How can i open apple maps with this links?

```
 func openMaps (latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    
    let googleMapsInstalled = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!)
    if googleMapsInstalled {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
                                        "?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&amp=ll=")!)
    } else {
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: nil)
    }
}
```